# How to remove the checkbox from primeng multiSelect?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have tried using `ng-template' to display only the label but the checkbox still displays by default. How can I change this default behaviour?

Here's the code using `ng-template`......
`

```html
<p-multiSelect [options]="conditionList" formControlName="condition" defaultLabel="Select Conditions"
    [showToggleAll]="false" scrollHeight="300px">
   <ng-template let-condition pTemplate="item">
     <div>{{condition.label}}</div>
   </ng-template>
</p-multiSelect>`
```

Comment: Maybe, you can use the component dropdown. I leave the documentation: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v8.2.9-lts/#/dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize MulitiSelect style overcoming View Envapsulation. It can be done in three ways:

1. Place the selector in global style, e.g. style.scss:

```
p-multiselect
.p-multiselect-panel
.p-multiselect-items
.p-multiselect-item
.p-checkbox {
   display: none;    
}
```

2. Palace the above override in compoennt.scss but add ::ng-deep:

```
::ng-deep {
    p-multiselect
    .p-multiselect-panel
    .p-multiselect-items
    .p-multiselect-item
    .p-checkbox {
       display: none;    
    }
}
```

3. Without ::ng-deep but disable view encapsulation:

```
@Component({
  ...
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1: Create two new theme.scss entries:

```
   .disable-check .p-multiselect-panel .p-multiselect-header .p-checkbox {
    display:none;
   }

   .disable-check .p-multiselect-panel .p-multiselect-items .p-checkbox {
    visibility:hidden;
   }
```

2: Add disable-check class to p-multiselect element:

```
   <p-multiSelect class="disable-check" [group]="true" optionLabel="item" 
   optionValue="valor"  [options]="ItemOptions" >
```